# How Can I Perform A Complex Calculation on a UserForm?

Tags: excel, vba, formula, userform, commandbutton

[UserForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tpDc.png) [Code Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tpDc.png)I am trying to perform a complex calculation from values that are entered into my userform by using a commandbutton to do the work.

So here are a few of the codes that i have tried since i started.
This is on that i just wanted to try to see if it was even placing a value.

```
[Private Sub CommandButton_Click()
VoltsDropBox.Text = Val(LengthBox) * 2
End Sub][1]

Private Sub CommandButton_Click()
Dim Length As Long
Dim Amps As Single
Dim Ohms As Single
Dim Volts As Single
Length = CSng(LengthBox.Text)
Amps = CSng(AmpsBox.Text)
Ohms = CSng(ResistanceBox.Text)
Volts = Resistance * (Length * 2) * Amps / 1000
VoltsDropBox.Value = Volts
End Sub
```

This is the calculation that i am trying to perform
Resistance * (Length * 2) * Amps / 1000

Comment: Seems pretty straight forward. What *problem* are you having?

Comment: Whenever i click the command button it doesn't display any values. Its like its not running. I am just unsure why.

Comment: I accomplished it with this (Me.ResistanceBox + 0) * (Me.LengthBox + 0) * 2 * (Me.AmpsBox + 0) / 1000
The plus Zero converts the text to a integer